# Samba drive mount issue

Tags: networking, samba

Ive had samba installed on my pi for some time now and had setup a mount for my windows 10 laptop to access on it.  It had been working well for a month now.  Yesterday I reserved my pi a IP on my router - so when connecting to a database I setup it was always a consistent IP.

Now on my windows 10 pc under network the mount stopped working under the original name (RASPBERRYPI) and only works under the reserved IP I assigned it.  It still works but im confused why the RASPBERRYPI doesnt allow connections now and if its related to setting up the reserved IP.

Screenshot below.  RASPBERRYPI is what had been working for a month. 192.168.1.44 is the reserved IP I assigned it and the mount only works there now.

[image: network]

When I enter the user and password for the drive I setup I get the following error.

[image: error]

Comment: You did NOT assign "a static IP on my router" - you may have RESERVED an IP address. Either way this is a Windows problem - nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: windoze may be "remembering" the old IP for the raspberry pi - oh, and by the way it's "samba" ... not sambda as you typed every time - perhaps searching for issues using samba may yield some results

Comment: thx both. made updates to question.  regarding windoze - what exactly is that and can i control/reset to get back to how it previously worked?

Comment: @matthewmturner: Assuming your RPi retains the address you have reserved for it, you may be able to [use this as a guide](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-edit-your-windows-hosts-file) to helping your Windows machine find the RPi.